# pdfsharp hyperlink AddDocumentLink not working on touchscreen Android

Tags: pdfsharp, touchscreen

MY code generates the PDF fine, and all links work on Desktop, but on mobile i cannot get the links working with touchscreen.

Any advice would be appriciated

```
        rect = New XRect(100, heightinpage, 50, 15)
        prect = New PdfRectangle(gfxref(pagecounter).Transformer.WorldToDefaultPage(rect))
        page(pagecounter).AddDocumentLink(prect, loopcontent)
        gfxref(pagecounter).DrawRectangle(XBrushes.Beige, rect)
```

Comment: Do you have other PDFs with links that work on mobile?

Comment: Yes, i have checked this, its an MS Xamarin documentation PDF

Comment: So just check in the PDF what is different between the links that work and the links that do not work.

Comment: thanx for the great advice, but this hardly will help me solve the problem with pdfsharp, this uses the code AddDocumentLink

thanx for your effort

Comment: Thanks for the great comment. I don't have the mobile to test it, I don't have the PDF that works. Maybe AddDocumentLink should do more to be compatible with mobiles. If the links work when you click them in Adobe Reader then I assume there is no problem with PDFsharp - just something that PDFsharp could do better.

Comment: Thanxs for your time